# Не работает readlines() в python

Tags: python

Есть файл 1.txt с содержимым:
1
2
3
4
5

Нужно прочитать этот файл из питона. Использую код:

```
file = open('1.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines)
print(len(lines))
file.close()
```

На вывод получаю: []
0 
Файл точно существует и он точно не пустой, находится в той-же директории что и сам скрипт *.py

Comment: Файл находится в той же директории, что и скрипт чтения?

Comment: `file = open('./1.txt', 'r')` вот так попробуйте

Comment: не помогло так, пробовал

Comment: ага, у всех работает, а у него не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот файл, к которому у вас есть доступ, точно пустой.
При несуществующем получите ошибку, а при заполненном:

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
5
```

Вероятно, нужный файл лежит где-то в другом месте у вас.
Поищите по диску поиском все "1.txt" файлы.

Comment: Вы считаете что я дурак?)

Comment: Последний комментарий не очень к месту. Но все так, как я написал. У вас доступ к пустому файлу. Я просто специально для вас проверил у себя все три случая:-)

Comment: Да. возможно дурак) python как проект развернут в папке, в которой создал подпапку с файлом, и скриптом, а скрипт считает родительскую директорию не в которой он находится, а ту, где развернут проект.

Я не знаю как по другому это объяснить, но решение я нашел, спасибо :)

Comment: "Спасибо", это, конечно, здорово, но примите один из двух ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Если вот так не сработает, то у вас в директории со скриптом пустой файл

```py
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('1.txt')

file = file_path.open('r', encoding='utf-8')
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines)
file.close()
```